# how to set a wallpaper as default one in Windows 7 via the registry

Tags: windows-7

I want to set a default wallpaper so that my admin does not change it from the server. I can even tweak the registry if need be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [bginfo from Microsoft Windows SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557).

Now I have some useful information as my desktop background.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i can understand studiohack point of view but as you can find some answers by STFW, i will provide some answers. Moderators will delete the whole thread if it doesn't respect the rules of stackexchange websites.

Though, if this thread remains, IMHO, we could give some clues to answer saravanan question :

- you can change the wallpaper by Right-click on a pic within Windows Explorer > **Set as wallpaper** (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327998)
- if you have access to the registery, you can change this key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop** (http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-98-2000-me-xp-2003-vista/122890-changing-desktop-background-set-administrator-policy.html)

Btw, as for the battle between security administrators and hackers, this thread could also help the admins who want to push their wallpaper to their users by preventing them to access these workarounds.

At last, @saravanan, if you think the wallpaper prevents you from working properly, maybe you could try to **talk with your system administrators, HR department or whoever wants to have this wallpaper** on every computer of the company. That would probably be a better way to react.

Regards,

Max

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the workaround is applicable to winxp only and not to win7. anyway got to work with the same desktop wallpaper............

Comment: sorry - i missed that win7 point

Answer (score 0):

Saravanan, you could fiddle around with Group Policy to change the permissions. So instead of letting the admin to block you, YOU block the admin :)
See here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a1ebfe81-421e-4630-8c1f-8068222ee533/wallpaper-via-group-policy-and-windows-7

Anyway, if I would want to do that I would use a dedicated wallpaper changer program. You can set one of these babies to change the wallpaper every x minutes. This one can even do it ONE TIME PER SECOND!! So, no matter what the admin does to your wallpaper, the program will override its changes.

Anyway, there is a chance that the admin won't invite you next time he buys pizza!